# Falta de "participación"

Tags: discusión, votos

Vale, puede que sea muy opinión personal. Pero, ¿Por qué hay tantas preguntas con ningún voto? Ni positivo, ni negativo. Preguntas incluso con múltiples respuestas, algunas con respuestas validadas.

Si visitas una pregunta puede que no, pero si respondes a una pregunta, valora la pregunta.

Y lo mismo para respuestas validadas sin voto. OP, ya que alguien te ha solucionado el problema, dale un voto aunque sea.

Comment: Considero en este caso agregar algunas preguntas que hayas visto y que consideres que deban tener votos/preguntas/comentarios = participación.
Creo además que la [respuesta del usuario "sstan"](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/943/78) explica en detalle algunas explicaciones a la que añadiría: no todos los usuarios de SO son igual de activos en el sitio, es básicamente, una cuestión de **oportunidad** y **colaboración**.

Comment: no puse ejemplos de preguntas y respuestas porque es mi opinion, pensar que esas merecen valoracion. y hablo de manera generica. no totas las preguntas pueden ser neutras. algunas son intresantes, otras están mal formuladas o no tienen sentido. tanto para bien como para mal hay que opinar.

Comment: Precisamente me estaba planteando lo mismo, llevo poco tiempo registrado en SO en español, he visto muchas preguntas de gente con respuestas mas que correctas en la que no se ha aceptado ninguna respuesta como correcta, incluso cuando el propio usuario que pregunta ha escrito un comentario como que le habían solucionado el tema. Tal vez es cuestión de desconocimiento de los mecanismos de la plataforma...

Comment: @VictorGimeno el mecanismo es bien fácil. Y votar es gratis (con un limite al día). Tampoco puedes esperar recibir voto si uno mismo no vota

Comment: @lois6b concretamente me refería a si saben que tienen que dar una respuesta por válida, votar si que se ve más natural

Comment: Personalmente en SO voto mucho mas que aca, pq alla las preguntas son mas elaboradas o demuestran conocimiento muchas veces... Muchas de las preguntas de aca desgraciadamente parecen de estudiantes tratando de solucionar tareas (IMHO)

Comment: Ejemplo de una pregunta que no merece ni ser vista: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29539/editor-de-texto ... de estas hay montones.. es GIMME THE CODEZ PLEASE por todos lados.. en lugar de buscar soluciones reales. como le das puntos a algo asi? ni siquiera como incentivo.

Comment: Ojo que el OP debe tener 15 de reputación para poder votar a favor de cualquier respuesta, no siempre es el caso.

Comment: @rnd claro, no tiene reputación suficiente porque no le votan la pregunta xD

Comment: @lois6b exacto, si votas a alguien que no tiene buen criterio (ej: hizo una pregunta mala o muy basica) **le das privilegios**, es por eso que hay que tener cuidado con votar por votar. Si le das privilegios a alguien que no tiene buen criterio (aun no lo tiene, lo sabes por su pregunta) entonces puede votar y si llenamos el sitio de estos votantes, se desdibuja el sentido de los votos, que es medir el valor de una pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: @rnd claro! solo si se merece la reputación digo ehh. no hay que ir regalandola

Comment: @rnd: Tristemente, es obvio que ya existen varios votantes de esta índole. Veo varias preguntas que se cierran con razón, pero que tienen votos positivos, o respuestas con código que ni siquiera se puede compilar, y también reciben votos positivos. A la larga, esto va a dañar la reputación de SOes.

Comment: @sstan puedes votar a negativo. Puedes inclusive publicar aquí en meta para discutir si dicha publicación, pregunta o respuesta, es adecuada y que la comunidad lo revise con más detalle.

Answer (score 27):

Buena pregunta. Pueden haber diferentes explicaciones.

En lo personal, me abstengo de votar si no tengo el conocimiento necesario en el campo en cuestión para juzgar la calidad de la pregunta o la respuesta. Aunque pudiera parecer que siempre sea una buena idea votar de forma positiva para "encomiar" al autor por su participación, no quisiera, por más bien intencionado que sea, que por causa de mi voto vaya a promover información incorrecta o de baja calidad. Esto tendría un efecto muy negativo para el sitio a largo plazo, ya que nuestros futuros lectores desconfiarían de la calidad del contenido del sitio, y no volverían mas. Se supone que los votos reflejan la calidad del contenido, sea en forma de preguntas o respuestas. Y si no estoy capacitado para juzgar la calidad, prefiero no votar, y dejar que los expertos voten para el beneficio de los visitantes futuros.

Pero para las preguntas donde sí me considero suficientemente capacitado para juzgar su calidad, entonces voto según lo que sugiere el botón de voto. O sea, un voto positivo si `Esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara`. Y mas bien un voto negativo si `Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil`.

Al menos, así lo he hecho siempre en el StackOverflow en inglés. Pero en este sitio estoy tratando de ser menos severo en cuanto a los votos negativos, ya que la comunidad es muy nueva y no deseo espantar a los nuevos usuarios innecesariamente (que alguien me corrija si sienten que esto es mala idea). Mas bien, me he propuesto que, en vez de votar negativamente, de dejar comentarios constructivos para ayudar a las personas a formular preguntas de mejor calidad. Es algo en lo que estoy tratando de mejorar actualmente.

La pregunta tiene que ser muy pobre para que le dé un voto negativo. Y en el caso de las respuestas, doy un voto negativo si la respuesta es definitivamente incorrecta o hasta peligrosa para OP y/o cualquier futuro lector que base su trabajo en esa respuesta.

> Si visitas una pregunta puede que no, pero si respondes a una pregunta, valora la pregunta.

No porque le doy respuesta a una pregunta significa que atomáticamente voy a votar a favor de esa misma pregunta. A veces la pregunta es de muy baja calidad, pero a pesar de eso, logro "interpretarlo" y dejarle una respuesta para intentar ayudar a OP. Me parece que el voto a favor o en contra de una pregunta debería ser independiente de la respuesta, y debería limitarse a si la pregunta en sí es de buena o mala calidad.

> Y lo mismo para respuestas validadas sin voto. OP, ya que alguien te ha solucionado el problema, dale un voto aunque sea.

100% de acuerdo. Si la respuesta contesta su pregunta, OP debería marcar el "check" para aceptar la respuesta y además votar a favor de ella. Y si hubo otras respuestas que le fueron útiles, aunque no las pueda aceptar todas, debería votar a favor de ellas también.

Sin embargo, no estoy de acuerdo cuando los que hacen la pregunta sistemáticamente votan a favor de *todas* las respuestas que reciben (sean correctas o no), como para agradecerles de haber tomado el tiempo de contestar su pregunta. A veces noto esto, y nuevamente, siento que esto podría afectar negativamente la confianza que nuestros futuros lectores le tengan a la calidad del contenido en SOes.

Comment: wow, una respuesta muy elaborada! estoy de acuerdisimo. es obvio que si no conoces del tema no vas a valorar. Pero es lo que veo, en muchos otros sitios de SE, el tema voto va mas en serio. aqui no se ve actividad casi

Comment: Sinceramente, estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo. No lo podría haber expresado mejor. Sin embargo, no porque sea el sitio nuevo, si una pregunta es mala no se deba votar como tal. Llevo más de un año y medio en Stackoverflow en inglés y por experiencia estoy viendo que cada vez entran más preguntas de peor calidad aún habiendo un montón de moderadores detrás. Creo que si cortas el germen de raíz, es mucho más fácil controlarlo después. Aunque, por supuesto, es una opinión y respeto totalmente la idea de no votarlas para "que no se espanten" :)

Comment: Yo siempre le doy voto a todos los que me responden, ya que aunque una es la mejor respuesta todas contribuyen a aprender cosas nuevas o ver la solución de otras maneras.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta, se me pasó por alto en su día. La votaría positivamente... y sí, voy a hacerlo :)