# ¿Hay explicaciones de votos negativos?

Tags: discusión, soporte

En esta pregunta me he encontrado con que me han votado negativamente.

[Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31059/juntar-label-e-input-en-formulario)

He estado buscando en el perfil el motivo del negativo, con la única finalidad de aprender mis errores y para la próxima mejorar la pregunta (contenido como formato), pero no veo nada de nada.

¿Se podría implementar que al poner negativo haya que incluir una breve explicación? A igual que se hace cuando se edita que te obliga a realizar como mínimo seis cambios.

Personalmente me da igual la puntuación, es por el desconocimiento en si mismo de la acción.

Si me podéis brindar algo de luz al respecto os estaría muy agradecido.

Gracias.

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/955/por-qu%C3%A9-votan-negativo-sin-dar-ninguna-explicaci%C3%B3n-al-respecto

Comment: `¿Se podría implementar que al poner negativo haya que incluir una breve explicación? ` No se puede, el voto es secreto (y seguira siendolo). El forzar a poner un comentario rompería tal secreto.

Answer (score 9):

Sinceramente, no le veo nada malo a tu pregunta aunque si que veo cosas que se podrían mejorar:

- No pongas todo el código de tu web. Intenta focalizar en las partes importantes que afectan a tu problema.
- Relacionado con lo anterior, sería muy bueno que intentases buscar las clases que afectan a tus filas en este caso e intentar sugerir a los usuarios lo que crees que puede estar mal. En Firefox y en Google Chrome puedes ver las clases que afectan a cada elemento dándole click derecho sobre el elemento > Inspeccionar elemento o Inspeccionar.
- Intenta poner todos los datos posibles desde el principio. He visto que has realizado 4 ediciones de tu pregunta y en cada una o en la mayoría has añadido un trozo de código adicional.
- No pongas el código con un link como referencia sin citar nada de código en la pregunta. De esta manera, si alguna vez el link dejara de funcionar, como es el caso, la pregunta carece de validez para próximos usuarios.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, aunque no he sido el usuario que te ha dado el voto negativo, pienso que ha podido ser que te han dado negativo en una de las primeras ediciones de la pregunta, ya que a simple vista era bastante pobre. Por lo demás, no creo que debas preocuparte, aunque si tener en cuenta los consejos anteriores.

La verdad que yo hace poco también hice una pregunta aquí en meta sobre porque la gente no daba respuesta en los votos negativos y yo vería muy bien que se implementara un tipo de obligación de poner comentario a la hora de realizar votos negativos para forzar al usuario un poco a hacer una crítica constructiva del voto negativo hacia el usuario que ha posteado la pregunta/respuesta. Pienso que serviría mucho mejor para que los usuarios pudieran aprender de sus errores. 
Sin embargo, desconozco completamente si esto sería posible de implementarse y de si sería muy costoso realizarlo.

Hasta entonces, yo dejo comentarios en las preguntas/respuestas añadiendo el motivo de mi voto negativo (excepto en las que son muy pobres, que directamente marco el voto negativo) para que los usuarios puedan aprender. A la vez, me gusta que dejen también una crítica constructiva junto al voto negativo para aprender yo también.

Espero haberte solucionado las dudas que pudieras tener.

Comment: muchas gracias, tomaré nota de lo que me has indicado para futuros casos. Como he comentado creo que sería positivo que las críticas (puntos negativos) vengan sucedidos de una breve explicación.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo!

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Se podría implementar que al poner negativo haya que incluir una breve explicación?

Para proponer que se modifique la forma en la que funciona este sitio, habría que publicar una pregunta con la etiqueta [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva).

Cabe mencionar que cada vez que uno realiza un voto negativo, un diálogo emergente recomienda colocar un comentario:

Imagen:
[image]

Texto:

> Considera añadir un comentario si crees que se puede mejorar esta publicación.

Lo anterior es lo que se ha dispuesto como regla, según entiendo, en todos los sitios de Stack Exchange.

En lo personal dudo mucho que se modifique esta característica por un lado porque lo que se quiere es que los usuarios votemos más<sup>1</sup> ya sea de forma positiva o negativa, no menos.

<sup>1</sup>: [Falta de "participación"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/941/falta-de-participaci%c3%b3n)