# Cada vez es más notoria la falta de votos para las preguntas

Tags: discusión, votos, privilegios

Ya hace varias semanas que los que me ven por el chat, escuchan que me quejo siempre de lo mismo...

Ya me parece extraño que la gente que contesta preguntas ni siquiera considere buena la pregunta (que puede ser, no digo que no), sino que hasta preguntas con más de una respuesta no tengan votos. Y ni siquiera se toman el trabajito de arreglar lo que consideren que está mal.

Pero hoy ya fue demasiado: al abrir la página principal en este momento (o hace 10 minutos), me encuentro con lo siguiente:

[image: pagina principal]

Lo grave de todo esto no es que no haya votos, que puede pasar, sino que no se sabe cuáles preguntas son buenas y cuáles malas.

<strike>Entonces lo que propongo es que ya que el sitio se va a graduar, si de alguna manera para favorecer que se voten cosas, y que la gente necesite votos en sus preguntas y respuestas, se dupliquen los puntos necesarios para obtener privilegios, o los privilegios mas chicos requieran mas puntos, así obligamos a los usuarios a trabajar un poco en el sitio también.</strike>

Escucho opiniones e ideas...

Comment: Related: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/941/falta-de-participaci%C3%B3n

Comment: `Lo grave de todo esto es .. que no se sabe cuáles preguntas son buenas y cuáles malas.` eso debes saberlo por ti mismo.

Comment: @EmanuelVe al igual que no puedes juzgar un libro por su portada no puedes juzgar una pregunta por su titulo, la falta de imaginación o la dificultad a la hora de expresarse buscando un buen titulo para la pregunta puede que haga el titulo de la pregunta menos llamativo, pero no por ello va a ser peor pregunta, y viceversa.

Comment: @AndoniAlda casi lo mismo es lo que dije, pero siendo... que no puedes juzgar una pregunta por sus votos. Debes leerla y tomar tu propia decision sin dejarte influenciar por los mismos. no por que tenga 100 votos es una buena pregunta necesariamente y viceversa.

Comment: @EmanuelVe entonces, bajo tu punto de vista el sistema de votos es algo que no funciona?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **TL;DR** Propongo que cada uno invite a los contestadores a votar en las preguntas que responden. Propongo una encuesta para saber si sabemos para que son los votos.

No estoy seguro que el voto se promueva haciendo los privilegios más difíciles de conseguir (en mi opinión se inhibiría el voto).

La realidad es que no conocemos las causas que provocan esta situación. Sospecho que no hay una única causa. Por ejemplo, no creo que la razón por la que un recién llegado no vote sean las mismas que las razones de un usuario con mas de 5k votos.

Personalemente, estoy convencido **que la empresa StackExchange no hará nada por ayudarnos** así que cualquier propuesta que implique *modificar*, *crear* funcionalidades, o cualquier cambio en el sitio es una pérdida de tiempo.

Creo que algo que podría ayudar, sería **la promoción de los votos**. No es algo que requiera que SE haga algo (que sabemos que no hará) y cada persona, tu, yo o cualquier usuario, en la medida de nuestras posibilidades, si tenemos tiempo o ganas, y sin rendirle cuentas a nadie, podemos hacer.

Por ejemplo, al ver una pregunta respondida, pero sin un voto, podemos ***ademas de votar nosotros mismo***, dejar un mensaje, tipo:

> *“Hola @MuchosPuntos, he visto tu excelente respuesta a esta pregunta y quisiera pedirte, ya que te tomaste el tiempo en escribirla, si podrías dedicarle un segundo más para votarla de acuerdo a tu criterio. Sabes que los votos ayudan no solo al usuario sino también contribuyen a la mejora de la calidad del sitio. Te pido que lo consideres.”*

Que conste que no estamos pidiendo un voto positivo, solo que considere votar. Sabemos que que la o el usuario @MuchosPuntos conoce el funcionamiento del sitio y como funciona el sistema de privilegios, solo queremos recordarle que si consideró (por las razones que fueran) dedicarle una parte de su valioso tiempo en contestar, puede dedicarle un segundito a votar.

Bueno, esa es mi propuesta. Yo la voy a empezar a aplicar hoy mismo, no tienen que estar de acuerdo conmigo, por supuesto. Ni hacer lo que yo hago. Pero tampoco pueden impedirlo. =)

---

Ahora, ya como cartita a Santa Clós, tengo esta propuesta, para el gestor de la comunidad.

### Propuesta

Es posible crear una encuesta (un enlace a una encuesta de esas de Google o como sea) para conocer el grado en el que los ususarios nuevos, frecuentes, experimentados o muchosPuntos conocen **y comprenden** el uso de los votos y el sistema de privilegios.

Sin que sea una lista definitiva, exhaustiva o ideal, pienso en las siguientes preguntas:

- Conoces el sistema de votos
- Cuál fue el privilegio más reciente que ganaste
- Cuál fue la medalla más reciente que ganaste
- Te interesa ganar una medalla en particular
- etc., y cosas asi.

El objetivo de la encuesta es conocer **a que factor** prestarle más atención para su promoción.

1. A la importancia de los votos en las preguntas y respuestas como indicador de calidad.
2. A los privilegios y la moderación colectiva
3. A las medallas y la *ludificación* de SOes.
4. A cualquier otra cosa que no se me ocurra.

Con una encuesta podríamos tomar decisiones basadas en datos. Podríamos dedicar nuestros recursos, como individuos y como comunidad, al aspecto que tenga más impacto para la comunidad. Podríamos establecer objetivos, medibles, retadores y alcanzables. Metas, retos, indicadores.

Pero necesitamos medir.

y ya.

Comment: De hecho la empresa se llama Stack Overflow, y la red de sitios se llama Stack Exchange.

Comment: Igual nos batea...

Comment: He seguido el consejo de toledano. He puesto el comentario que él sugiere en 7 respuestas en que la pregunta tenía 0 votos. Todas ellas respuestas de entre las 10 últimas respuestas de toledano.

Comment: Estás enfermo @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos es una lástima que pertenezcas a esta comunidad. Pero gracias por la atención inmerecida. Por cierto, ya pasé los 3 mil puntos que era uno de mis objetivos antes de la graduación \o/

Comment: ¡Cuánto amor! :)

Comment: @toledano, me gusta el comentario/mensaje para animar a los usuarios a votar.

Answer (score 2):

## En realidad es notoria?

¿Qué merece votos?

*esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación; es útil y clara*  +1

*esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil*  -1

En el ejemplo que muestras si bien no hay votos, casi tampoco hay vistas. Pienso que los votos de las preguntas llegarán, pero por quien? por quien considere útil la respuesta. Cuando tengo un problema busco que alguien haya respondido la pregunta, si encuentro que alguien pregunto, y otro respondio y fue excelente y me funciono, vaya merece un voto! pero si no estoy buscando, si no es útil para alguien mas que el que esta preguntando.. ¿porque merece votos?

## Propuesta

*Dale tiempo.*

El sitio crecerá, y miles de nuevos programadores encontrarán un sitio único en su especie, encontraran que muchos otros antes de ellos se plantearon inquietudes similares, y recibieron respuestas asombrosas, y los votos llegarán.