# ¿Cómo se consigue la medalla Reversión, cuando es posible cerrar y eliminar preguntas "malas"?

Tags: discusión, medallas

Tras los acontecimientos ocurridos con el cierre de una pregunta varias veces (tema expuesto en [¿Podríamos proteger la pregunta "¿Es posible saber cuando rotas el móvil en Unity?"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1987/es-posible-proteger-esta-pregunta) y [Pregunta cerrada con votos negativos en mi opinion no fueron puestos por la pregunta en si](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1942/pregunta-cerrada-con-votos-negativos-en-mi-opinion-no-fueron-puestos-por-la-preg))

Me pregunto cómo la gente consigue la [medalla Reversión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal).

Actualmente nadie la tiene. Ya de por sí es difícil de conseguir, pues el usuario que realizó la pregunta puede que la elimine para no perder en este caso 30 de rep (al menos 5 votos negativos).

En uno de los hilos comenté que la reputacion no era el foco para recuperar la pregunta "o intentar", pero **esta vez** me pregunto: ¿se quiere borrar la pregunta porque es *mala* o para evitar que alguien gane la medalla Reversión antes que él? Quizás estoy siendo un poco injusto con la exposición, pero visto lo visto como dicen por algunos lugares: piensa mal y acertarás.

<sub>En Meta la tiene Luiggi Mendoza, felicidades por ello: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal</sub>

Comment: La medalla [Buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) sólo requiere un +25 (sin condiciones en la pregunta) y aún así muy pocos la obtuvieron. Reversión es una medalla particularmente difícil, ¿por qué pensás que se esperaría que alguien la gane a esta altura? ... Análogamente, [Excelente respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) no la ganó nadie (aún), ¿no será simplemente una cuestión de que [se debería votar más](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1967/127)?

Comment: @Mariano su ultimo comentario pienso que sale un poco de la tematica, o yo me perdi.

Comment: @Mariano quizas la pregunta deberia de extenderse a si se tienen que eliminar las preguntas "malas" las cuales cuentan con una o varias respuestas ya sean aceptadas o no, sin tener en cuenta si alguna de las respuesta tiene algun +1 antes de pedir su eliminacion por concideracion. Saludos

Comment: _piensa mal y acertaras_... es _piensa con malicia y acertaras_ ? o piensa mal y acertaras se refiere a que los `assert` fallaran ?

Comment: @EmanuelVe no entiendo bien su comentario, ni tampoco soy experto en refranes, pero yo siempre he escuchado lo mencionado, es mas si pone, piensa mal y acertaras, en google tiene mas entradas que piensa con malicia y acertaras, pero como digo no se cual es la forma correcta o la mas estandar. Saludos

Comment: @Mariano bueno yo me quedo sin poder optar a la medalla por esa pregunta, ademas de ganarme -1 por exponer el caso, pero por lo menos el tiempo que perdi en publicar la respuesta, los post en meta relacionados, comentarios y demas, si sirven para que alguien pueda optar en un futuro a esa respuesta y le ayude, pues ya es algo. Saludos

Comment: Realmente parece que estés pidiendo la medalla :P

Comment: Bromas aparte, esta medalla es rara: premia a los usuarios por algo que no recomienda hacer. Actualmente en [so] es solo una medida del _efecto Meta_, pues es como se está consiguiendo.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%c3%b3n-completa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuación, a manera de ejemplo, uno y sólo un posible escenario de los muchos que podría haber considerando por  las "combinaciones y permutaciones" de las diferentes acciones, ciclos de votar para cerrar - reabrir y el caso de que la pregunta sea bloqueada.

1. El cuestionador publica una pregunta
2. El respondedor publica una respuesta (no ha votado)
3. 5 votantes votan negativamente la pregunta, votan para cerrar la pregunta y votan positivamente la respuesta.

   - La pregunta se cierra.

     - Ya no es posible publicar nuevas respuestas pero sí es posible votar la respuesta ya publicada.
4. 15 votantes votan positivamente la respuesta

> **Notas** :
>
> - Una vez que una pregunta ha obtenido una respuesta con votos positivos, no puede ser eliminada por su autor, sólo a través de votos de eliminar.
> - Se puede votar en preguntas cerradas pero no en preguntas bloqueadas

Comment: Gracias por responder y si me puedo imaginar cientos de permutaciones de como podria lograse ganar la medalla, pero una de las cuestiones, es que si los usuarios pueden borrar/eliminar este tipo de preguntas en cualquier momento se hace dificil, "mas aun" el obtener esta medalla, otra cosa seria por ejemplo que el lugar cuente con muchos votantes y en un momento se consigan los votos necesarios "y aunque esta se elimine posiblemente se quede con la medalla el que la gane", pero una de las cosas que dejo en un comentario...

Comment: ...es si se deberia de tener algun tipo de consideracion a la hora de votar para eliminar este tipo de preguntas. Saludos

Comment: Tal vez la pregunta como está es "demasiado amplia" o sería bueno hacer una pregunta de seguimiento incluyendo lo que mencionas en el comentario, en cualquier caso, estoy de acuerdo que la medalla en cuestión es particularmente rara, sin embargo, creo que en lugar de centrar nuestra atención en esta medalla, sería mejor ver formas promover el sitio, ser percibidos como una comunidad que recibe bien a los nuevos al tiempo que votamos más y mejor.

Comment: ja ahora puede añadir a la lista de dificultades eliminar/borra/ **bloquear** esto deberia de ser una medalla no de oro sino de diamante. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel: He extendido el párrafo inicial y agregado unas notas al final :)

Comment: Eso que comentas -> *Una vez que una pregunta ha obtenido...* es muy interesante no lo sabia y me parece muy acertado en cuanto a los puntos que pueda tener el usuario de la respuesta, y sobre todo al tema de la medalla que es lo que trata este tema, gracias por ese dato no lo concia. Saludos