# ¿Es válido darle un voto positivo a respuestas que ya fueron aceptadas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, votos

Dentro de la comunidad, se reciben gran cantidad de respuestas a múltiples y variadas preguntas; por lo tanto votar positivo a mas de una sería conveniente bajo las siguientes condiciones:

> 1. Conozco perfectamente el tema tratado en la pregunta, por lo tanto valoro la calidad de la respuesta y otorga un +1 como aprobación del
>      contenido
> 2. Al revisar una respuesta que no recibió calificación compruebo que cumple con las condiciones necesarias para haber incluso sido aceptada
> 3. Sirve tener respuestas de calidad y acordes a la pregunta calificadas aún cuando no fueron aceptadas para que posteriores
>      consulteantes valoren mas opciones de resolución

Es importante que al momento de revisar las respuestas que ya fueron aceptadas o que estan recibiendo alta cantidad de puntaje, continuar haciendolo por que en el momento en que se hagan posteriores consultas; las personas que revisen tendrán seguridad que es una respuesta de calidad que a mas de un integrante de la comunidad le ayudó.

Ayuda desde el momento en que las personas que mas activamente participan en la comunidad sigan aportando a la misma.

Como se menciona en un punto superior, si se observan respuestas que ya fueron aceptadas lo ideal sería darles un +1 siempre y cuando se apeguen a la normatividad de SO de este modo a mayor cantidad de votos positivos de los temas que cada uno dominemos se ayuda a fomentar mantener en lo mas alto del ranking las mejores respuestas, aún cuando estas ya tuvieran "algo de tiempo" de haber sido otorgadas.

> Si se da voto positivo cuando la respuesta y/o la pregunta no solo
>   cumple con las reglas del foro si no que aporta valor de conocimiento
>   a los eventuales consultantes de las mismas en momentos posteriores,
>   se puede ayudar a revertir la tendencia de no calificar o calificar
>   muy poco

Comment: Posiblemente relacionado con [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Comment: Según he observado para cierta parte de la comunidad resultan confusas las publicaciones que usan una pregunta retórica como título. Esto es comprensible debido a que se trata de un sitio de preguntas y respuestas preponderantemente técnicas aún y cuando sean válidas las discusiones en Meta. Considero que es mejor otras formas de titular las publicaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconozco si ya habías pasado por aquí, pero veo que es tu primera publicación así que **bienvenido como autor a Meta**-

Me agrada mucho que te hayas tomado el tiempo de manifestar tu interés en la votación de respuestas ya que esto es uno de los elementos fundamentales del modelo.

Te dejo enlaces a otras publicaciones en meta relacionadas con el tema. Tal vez te interese participar en las mismas, utilizarlas para enriquecer tu publicación o ambas cosas :)

P&R relacionados

- [Falta de "participación"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/941/65)
- [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1075/65)
- [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)

Comment: No entiendo cómo esto es una respuesta. Es muy útil, pero como comentario :)

Comment: @fedorqui: Que bueno que lo encuentras útil. ¡Gracias por mencionarlo!